# Nodejs Github api gist create - receiving Socket Hang up

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I'm trying to create Gist through github api - using npm module "github" (https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-github/)

I have this code

```
  var gh = new GitHubApi({
    version: "3.0.0"
  });

  gh.authenticate({
    type: "oauth",
    token: data.token
  });

  gh.user.get({}, function (err, data) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);

    var blob = {};
    blob.repo = commitData.repo;
    blob.user = commitData.user;
    blob.content = commitData.content;
    blob.encoding = commitData.encoding;
        gh.gitdata.createBlob(blob, function (err, blob) {
           console.log(err);
           console.log(blob);
           cb('failed');
       });
  });
```

The problem is that createBlob function is receiving this

```
{ 
  defaultMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
  message: 'socket hang up',
  code: '500' 
}
```

I'm running my app on heroku free instance (its based on express).

Thanks a lot, I am solving it for days and still cant make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe api.github.com had some outage?

Strange, but [status.github.com](http://status.github.com) [**report for Jul 19**](https://status.github.com/messages/2012-06-19) shows that all was just ok for that time.